# How to migrate Azure Functions v3 to .net core 5.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have upgraded all assemblies in an Azure Function v3 project to version 5.0 but I am unable to run the function. Here it is my function's csproj file's partial definition:

```json
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

What's the necessary workaround to make this function with .NET 5? Google did not yield anything conclusive.

> Further info: 5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

This is one of the error messages that I get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Functions don't support .NET 5 yet, they estimate this to be ready end of this year. See this GitHub comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6674#issuecomment-726183256

Comment: It supports .NET Core 5 as of yesterday. It has been in preview mode for awhile, but it is now GA.

Comment: Now that support for .Net Core 5 is live, could you update your accepted answer. The bottom one contains links with a lot of great stuff.

Comment: I am getting same error, is it resolved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment by @Marc is correct, currently Azure Functions do not support .net 5. Current ETA is a preview by end of year.

Please keep an eye on [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6674) for any updates.

Comment: Okay so in this case should we downgrade and use 3.0 on linux?

Comment: It's live as of yesterday.

Answer (score 12):

Azure functions team released support for `.Net 5` by introducing a new isolated process model to run .NET function apps.

You can read more about this in the [announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916).

To migrate you function app to `.Net 5` you can follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide).

Comment: Although that link does go to some of the best info out there on Azure Functions 5, it isn't a migration guide. Would love it if you could link to one.

Answer (score 3):

Dave Brock created a web page explaining the process using the preview bits. But I believe it should be close enough for the release bits. See [here](https://daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5).

Looks like Brandon Minnick's guide is more comprehensive. See [here](https://codetraveler.io/2021/02/12/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/).

Comment: Why do people keep linking guides for "creating" when the desire is to migrate existing code.

Comment: Looks to me that both linking guides do contain a lot of interesting things about migrating.